# When dynamically generating join condition as list in PySpark, How to apply "OR" in between the elements instead of "AND"?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am joining two dataframes site_bs and site_wrk_int1 and creating site_wrk using a dynamic join condition.

My code is like below:

```
join_cond=[ col(v_col) == col('wrk_'+v_col) for v_col in primaryKeyCols]  #result would be 
site_wrk=site_bs.join(site_wrk_int1,join_cond,'inner').select(*site_bs.columns)
```

join_cond will be dynamic and the value will be something like [ col(id) == col(wrk_id), col(id) == col(wrk_parentId)]

In the above join condition, join will happen satisfying both the conditions above. i.e., the join condition will be

```
id = wrk_id  and id = wrk_parentId
```

But I want or condition to be applied like below

```
id = wrk_id  or id = wrk_parentId
```

How to achieve this in Pyspark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since logical operations on `pyspark` columns return column objects, you can chain these conditions in the join statement such as:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as f


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "A", "A"),
    (2, "C", "C"), 
    (3, "E", "D"), 
], ['id', 'col1', 'col2'] 
)
df.show()
+---+----+----+
| id|col1|col2|
+---+----+----+
|  1|   A|   A|
|  2|   C|   C|
|  3|   E|   D|
+---+----+----+


df.alias("t1").join(
    df.alias("t2"),
    (f.col("t1.col1") == f.col("t2.col2")) | (f.col("t1.col1") == f.lit("E")),
    "left_outer"
).show(truncate=False)
+---+----+----+---+----+----+
|id |col1|col2|id |col1|col2|
+---+----+----+---+----+----+
|1  |A   |A   |1  |A   |A   |
|2  |C   |C   |2  |C   |C   |
|3  |E   |D   |1  |A   |A   |
|3  |E   |D   |2  |C   |C   |
|3  |E   |D   |3  |E   |D   |
+---+----+----+---+----+----+
```

As you can see, I get the `True` value for left rows with IDs 1 and 2 as `col1 == col2 OR col1 == E` which is `True` for three rows of my DataFrame. In terms of syntax, it's important that the Python operators (`| & ...`) are separated by closed brackets as in example above, otherwise you might get confusing `py4j` errors.

Alternatively, if you wish to keep to similar notation as you stated in your questions, why not use `functools.reduce` and `operator.or_` to apply this logic to your list, such as:

In this example, I have an `AND` condition between my column conditions and get `NULL` only, as expected:

```
df.alias("t1").join(
    df.alias("t2"),
    [f.col("t1.col1") == f.col("t2.col2"),  f.col("t1.col1") == f.lit("E")],
    "left_outer"
).show(truncate=False)
+---+----+----+----+----+----+
|id |col1|col2|id  |col1|col2|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+
|3  |E   |D   |null|null|null|
|1  |A   |A   |null|null|null|
|2  |C   |C   |null|null|null|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+
```

In this example, I leverage `functools` and `operator` to get same result as above:

```
df.alias("t1").join(
    df.alias("t2"),
    functools.reduce(
      operator.or_, 
      [f.col("t1.col1") == f.col("t2.col2"),  f.col("t1.col1") == f.lit("E")]),
    "left_outer"
).show(truncate=False)
+---+----+----+---+----+----+
|id |col1|col2|id |col1|col2|
+---+----+----+---+----+----+
|1  |A   |A   |1  |A   |A   |
|2  |C   |C   |2  |C   |C   |
|3  |E   |D   |1  |A   |A   |
|3  |E   |D   |2  |C   |C   |
|3  |E   |D   |3  |E   |D   |
+---+----+----+---+----+----+
```

Comment: operator.or_ is the one I am looking for. Thanks Napoleon.

Answer (score -3):

I am quite new in spark SQL.
Please notify me if this can be a solution.

```
site_wrk = site_bs.join(site_work_int1, [(site_bs.id == site_work_int1.wrk_id) | (site_bs.id == site_work_int1.wrk_parentId)], how = "inner")
```